# It does not display events in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler, kendo-template

my CustomEditorTemplate

```
<script id="customEditorTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div class="k-edit-label"><label for="title">Заголовок</label></div>
<div data-container-for="title" class="k-edit-field">
    <input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="title" required="required" data-bind="value:title">
  </div>
<div class="k-edit-label">
    <label for="start">Дата события</label>
  </div>
<div data-container-for="start" class="k-edit-field">
    <input type="text" 
           data-role="datetimepicker" 
           data-interval="15"
           data-type="date" 
           data-bind="value:start,invisible:isAllDay" 
           name="start"/>
    <input type="text" data-type="date" data-role="datetimepicker" data-bind="value:start,visible:isAllDay" name="start" />
    <span data-bind="text: startTimezone"></span>
    <span data-for="start" class="k-invalid-msg" style="display: none;"></span>
  </div>
<div class="k-edit-label"><label for="content">Текст</label></div>
<div data-container-for="content" class="k-edit-field">
    <textarea name="content" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value:content"></textarea>
  </div>
<div class="k-edit-label"><label for="active">Статус</label></div>
<div data-container-for="active" class="k-edit-field">
    <select id="active" data-bind="value:active" data-role="dropdownlist"
                    data-value-field="value" data-text-field="text">
      <option value="1">Показать</option>
      <option value="0">Скрыть</option>
  </select>
  </div>
```

create Kendo Scheduler JS:

```
        qwe.schCalendarOfEvents = $(".schCalendarOfEvents").kendoScheduler({
        date: new Date(),
        startTime: new Date(),
        height: 400,
        timezone: "Etc/UTC",
        views: [
            "day",
            "week",
        { type: "month", selected: true },
            "agenda",
            "timeline"
        ],
        selectable: true,
        //dataBinding: scheduler_dataBinding,
        //dataBound: scheduler_dataBound,
        save: scheduler_save,
     dataSource: {
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { from: "ID", type: "number" },
                        title: { from: "HEADER", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                        start: { type: "date", from: "NDATE" },
                        //end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                        //startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                        //endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                        content: { from: "CONTENT" },
                        active: { from: "ACTIVE" }
                    }
                        //recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                       // recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                       // recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                      //  ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
                      //  isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                    }
                }
            },
            editable: {
                template: $("#customEditorTemplate").html(),
            }
    }).data('kendoScheduler');
```

Scheduler Save Event:

```
function scheduler_save(e) {
    var header = $('input[name="title"]').val();
    var ndate = $('input[name="start"]').val();
    ndate = ndate + ":00";
    var content = $('textarea[name="content"]').val();
    var active = $('select#active').find("option:selected").val();
    $.post(rootUrl + 'Editor/InsertTblEvents', { header: header, ndate: ndate, content: content, active: active }, function (data) {
        if (data.ErrorMessage)
            alert(data.ErrorMessage);
        else {

        }
    });
}
```

My Model:

```
public class TblEvents 
    {
        public short ACTIVE { get; set; }

        public string CONTENT { get; set; }

        public string HEADER { get; set; }

        public DateTime? NDATE { get; set; }           
    }
```

For this model to be created EditorTemplate. I have Scheduler save event stores data in DataBase. But when I give DataSource it doesnt display in Scheduler

Comment: Write any advice, please ask